# Drafting Gmail Signature

Tags: gmail, email, email-signature

I created a signature in Google Docs and tried to copy/paste it into my Gmail Signature, but lost a lot of the formatting.
I don't have plain text checked.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your signature using the native to Google Mail signature tools.

[image]